# Pagination in one HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Here is working example https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/lxa0FF9yhw# that I need to work in one html file.

I am using this template to merge HTML, Css and javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            CSS goes here
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            JS goes here
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        HTML goes here
    </body>
</html>
```

But as a result I see all lines of table instead of pages.
Is this a problem with Bootstraping? I am including jQuery and javascript

```
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
<script src='script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I still see all lines in a result. I tried this code in https://jsfiddle.net/tfyqwLkr/. It also shows all lines of table.
How to include all required elements in this case?

Comment: Still the same. I also placed <script> includes. Also tried one in header and one in body and vise versa. I still see all pages.

Comment: what do you see in console. when I ran in jsfiddle, I got below errors. `jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: children.size is not a function TypeError: children.size is not a function` and `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: children.size is not a function` `k.fn.init.$.fn.pageMe `

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your Javascript just before the body end tag: `</body>`.

You might be calling DOM elements that haven't been parsed yet.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* CSS goes here */
        </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML goes here -->

        <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
        <script src='script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // JS goes here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT**: After posting your code, looks like you are trying to call `size()`, a [deprecated method](https://api.jquery.com/size/) since jQuery 3.0.

> Note: This method has been removed in jQuery 3.0. Use the .length property instead.

That throws some errors in the console. Change `children.size()` to `children.length`.

Check the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrbjfL9a/). (Line 23)

Comment: Thank you, but buttons are not appearing, just you are outputting to console log

Comment: Check the Fiddle, buttons are appearing. You just need to style them properly.